# Magento active category selection not working

Tags: magento

I have some issues with Magento selecting(deciding) which category is active.

We have multiple websites each with one store available. This is because the client wants different pricing on each store, planning to have a storefront for each of their frequent buyers. At the same time he does not want these stores to be visible for others but the representative of that specific company.

Because these have to be on the same domain (and all of the stores are to be in English) we decided we will use "Add Store Code to Urls" option from default(scope) in Configuration->General->Web. This way we now have mydomain.com/main for the main website and mydomain.com/york for the York website. And that seems to be working rather fine.

So we have a storefront and website called York and created a customer group called York. I prepared a script that is now in the header. This script checks the website name and if it matches York then checks the customer group. If both are York it will let you browse the storefront, if its not then it will redirect you to the login page. Any comments on this solution will be greatly appreciated too.

```
$gid = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
$group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($gid);

$cgc = "".$group->getCustomerGroupCode();
$wsn = "".Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getName();
//$wsn = "".Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
$lurl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); 
$currurl =  Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); 


if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
   $protocol = 'http';
} else {
   $protocol = 'https';
}

if($wsn === "York")
{
    if($cgc === "York"){
        //echo("OK:".$cgc); // nothing going on we belong to this store based on user group
    }else {
        if($protocol."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/york/customer/account/login/" !== $currurl && $protocol."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/york/customer/account/" !== $currurl && $protocol."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/york/customer/account/forgotpassword/" !== $currurl && "/york/customer/account/resetpassword/" !== $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']){
            echo("<script>window.location = '".$protocol."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/york/customer/account/login/';</script></head><body>NO ACCESS</body></html>");
            die();
        }
    }

}
```

But now when we believed we are ready we have noticed that when we select product from the listing Magento fails to add "active" class to the category in main navigation or selects rather randomly. It does not happen when we are on category listing page. And the breadcrumbs on the product page seem to have correct category listed too. Despite our efforts we cannot get the selection working.

I have tried commenting out the above script, change the configuration , flush cache and reindexed but it still is not playing nice. Furthermore I have copied the theme to my test Magento install and configured it same as the one in question but it works fine, I was not able to replicate the problem there.

Magento version is 1.8.1.0

Please any comments on the set-up we have or the script and our active category issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Does the producturl contain the category?

Comment: yes it does, urls look like this domain/main/furniture-and-upholstery/reception-chair-345.html, the breadcrumbs are selecting correctly but top navigation is either not selecting or selecting incorrectly

Comment: It's impossible to tell without knowing your template. The code displayed doesn't affect the navigation.

Comment: neither is the template here is where menu is added $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top')

Comment: <?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
                    <?php echo $_menu ?>
                </ul>
                <div class="sf-menu-block">
                    <div id="menu-icon"><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></div>
                    <ul class="sf-menu-phone">
                        <?php echo $_menu ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: i should probably add that this is first time sample data was tried too, has someone experienced similar problems with sample data